# Form is not submitted during FileUpload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, spring-webflow

I want to upload a file into my Weblogic server. My form is

```
 <h:form id="manualReplay" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<h:outputText value="UploadFile Here" /> :
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="output">
    <t:inputFileUpload value="#{serviceClass.uploadedFile}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>                                     
    <h:commandButton id="upload" value="upload" action="upload" />

</h:form>
```

My spring web flow Flow xml File

```
<view-state id="manualReplay" model="serviceClass" >    
   <transition on="upload" to="manualReplay">
       <evaluate expression="serviceClass.submit()"/>
   </transition>
</view-state>
```

My Bean Class

```
private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

public void submit() throws IOException {

    String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getName());
    String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
    byte[] bytes = uploadedFile.getBytes();
    }

public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
    return uploadedFile;
}

public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
}
```

But when the form is being submitted the page is just reloading without any errors.
Any ideas where i'm wrong.
When i remove the enctype this is working fine, but only for multipart/form-data it is happening!

Comment: Please, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. E.g. does the problem disappear when you remove that `<tr>`? No? Keep it out!

Comment: I copypasted that piece into my blank playground project and tried to run it. Indeed "nothing" happens. Also not when I remove that enctype, on contrary to what you said. It looks like that the bean or filter or what not who's responsible for processing that form is missing. You seem to be using a plain HTML element instead of a JSF component as well, which is confusing. You seem to be expecting that it's by default present in a blank JSF project using the most recent versions and with everything set to default. All in all it look like that you still haven't carefully read that MCVE link.

Comment: I am using jsf 2.1 which had no File tag and again i have changed to tomahawk tag and tried the same but it is giving me the same issue

Comment: "Flow xml" isn't recognizable as part of JSF. I have therefore no clue what you're talking about. You're probably talking about Spring Flow. In order to get the right attention, you'd need to retag (and reframe!!) the question.

Comment: I have just added a tag,i'm using spring web flow for controller

Comment: Okay, thus it works fine in a completely blank JSF project with everything set to default and without Spring Web Flow?

Comment: If you are using SWF, then you need to include in your config file: <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  <!--<property name="maxUploadSize" value="1024" />-->
 </bean>

Comment: @JavaGuy glad it helped you! Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SWF, then you need to include CommonsMultipartResolver in your config file:

```
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"> 
           <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1024" />//Set your file size limit here
    </bean>[enter link description here][1]
```